# How to check if a user has any entries they're an author of... in a plugin?

Tags: plugin-development

This seems pretty simple in a template; along the lines of

```
if( craft.entries.authorId(10) | length ){ ... }
```

But how do I do that from a plugin?

```
craft->entries->authorId(10)
```

doesn't seem to exist and I've been banging my head against the docs not knowing what I'm actually looking for...

[EDIT]

I now have the following code:

```
$entryCriteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
$entryCriteria->authorId = $existingUser->id;
$existingPages = $entryCriteria->find();

if ($existingPages) {
    AutoUserEntryPlugin::log('User already exists and has a page belonging to them; aborting.', LogLevel::Info);
    throw new Exception(Craft::t("You already have an account and a page created for you. Aborting. You have not been charged."));
} else {
    AutoUserEntryPlugin::log('User with ID ' . $existingUser->id . ' does not seem to have a page.', LogLevel::Info);
}
```

But with a user I know for a fact has an Entry for which they are the author, it's returning "User with ID 1198 does not seem to have a page".

Comment: Both Steve and Brad's answers (essentially the exact same code) should work, so there must be something amiss. What's the status of the entry – is it disabled or enabled?

Comment: Also, double check if the user with an ID `1198` has in fact authored any entries – easily done by checking for the integer `1198` in the `authorId` column in the `craft_entries` database table.

Comment: The entry is disabled!

OK, so I need to add a new criteria to say ignore the status... trying to figure that out now, thanks!

Comment: If the entry is disabled, that's your issue. Be advised that the `$entryCriteria->find` won't pull disabled entries by default, but you can add `$entryCriteria->status = null;` to the query to also include disabled entries.

Comment: That's the answer, and that's why this code wasn't working yesterday when I tried! Thanks!

Comment: Awesome. I'll edit Steve's answer to include that detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Getting entries in plugins is slightly different from within templates and you should read the details on [Working with Elements](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/working-with-elements) in a plugin in the Craft docs.

Taking that as a guide, you need to create an `ElementCriteriaModel` instance which selects the entries you are interested in:

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
$criteria->authorId = 10;
```

Note that the `ElementCriteriaModel` won't pull disabled entries by default. If you want to pull both enabled and disabled entries, you can add the `status` parameter to your query:

```
$criteria->status = null;
```

Finally, you need to call `find()` on the `ElementCriteriaModel` to fetch the entries matching your criteria:

```
$entries = $criteria->find();
```

Comment: It was the null status that was throwing me; didn't know about it! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
$entryCriteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
$entryCriteria->authorId = 10;
$entryModels = $entryCriteria->find();
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not seem to work :/ Edited my question to show example code...